# c++ update boost version issue

Tags: c++, boost

The thing is, recently  I installed a new version of boost on my ubuntu.. I had 1.46 and now I have 1.56. The problem I am facing is now some of the programs wont run since apparently they require:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

is there a bypass around this. How to solve the problem ?

Comment: recompile that program with new library?

Answer (score 1):

Boost versions are not binary compatible. That application needs boost-1.46.1 and it cannot use any other version.

Either install boost-1.46.1 or recompile and re-link your applications against the available boost version.